# How do I change the type of a value in a ResultSet or List?

Tags: java, groovy, resultset

I have a sql procedure, I access it in groovy (java) with the parameters I want and get back the cursor. With the help of ReSultSet, I return the data back as a dataset. But I am faced with a problem. The fields in the table are of 3 types: numeric, string, date. When I work already in groovy (java), then numeric is recognized as a number with a dot and therefore as a result I get numbers with ".0" at the end, although the record in the database was normal (without ".0"). For example, in the database the field was "10", but when running in groovy (java) I get "10.0".

```
OutParameter CUR_SERVICE = new OutParameter() {
                public int getType() {
                    return OracleTypes.CURSOR;
                }
            }

            try {
                sql.call("{call test.test (a => ?, b => ?, c => ?, pcur => ?)}"
                        , [a,
                           b,
                           c,
                           CUR_SERVICE
                ]) {
                    ResultSet row_service -> reader.readResultSet(row_service)

                }
}
```

Also I tried the second option. I put the data in the "List" and it worked like this, but in this case, to return it in the form of a dataset, I have to form "names", "types", and then only pass values ​​whose type must correspond to "types". As a result, there are already two problems:

1. BigDecimal (the same point)
2. timestamp (for a date field)

```
OutParameter CUR_SERVICE = new OutParameter() {
                public int getType() {
                    return OracleTypes.CURSOR;
                }
            }

            try {
                sql.call("{call test.test (a => ?, b => ?, c => ?, pcur => ?)}"
                        , [a,
                           b,
                           c,
                           CUR_SERVICE
                ]) {
                    ResultSet row_service -> //reader.readResultSet(row_service)

                        ResultSetMetaData md = row_service.getMetaData();
                        int columns = md.getColumnCount();
                        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
                        while (row_service.next()){
                            HashMap row = new HashMap(columns);
                            for(int i=1; i<=columns; ++i){
                                row.put(md.getColumnName(i),row_service.getObject(i));
                                def aabbcc = md.getColumnName(i)
                                aabbcc
                            }
                            list.add(row);
                        }

                        List names = list.inject(new LinkedHashSet<>()) { res, map ->
                            res.addAll map.keySet()
                            res
                        }.toList()


                        def typeMap = [:].withDefault { key -> "String" }
                        list.each { map ->
                            map.each { key, values ->
                                if (values != null) {
                                    typeMap[key] = values.getClass().simpleName
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        def types = names.collect { name -> typeMap[name] }

                        println(types)

                        reader.outputLinesSetHeaders(names, types)

                        list.each { e ->
                            reader.outputLines names.collect { e[it] }
                        }

                        reader.outputLinesEnd();
                        return null;

                }
}
```

Briefly what I need:

1. change the type from "BigDecimal" to "Integer" so that it can read "types" normally and the values ​​do not contain ".0"
2. change the type from "timestamp" to "String" so that "types" can be read normally and the values ​​are "11/19/2020 00:00", but not 11/19/2020 00:00 (not String).
   How should I do it? Or how, in the first case, just remove the ".0" even without changing the type?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could do this.  For (1) you get create values from the Integer as in:

```
    BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal(55);
    Integer y = new Integer(3);
    
    y = new Integer(x.intValue());
```

For (2) myTimestamp.toString() returns a string that can be parsed.